# Page not scrolling all the way to the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, height

I have just added this code to my page:

```
<script>
$(window).on('load resize',function(){
   var maxHeight = -1;
   $('.specification-columns').each(function() {
    maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
   });
   $('#specification').each(function() {
    $(this).height(maxHeight+24);
   });
 });
</script>
```

So that I can get the height of three divs, pick the tallest one and set the wrapper height to that. Since I put that code in, the page does not scroll all the way to the bottom, you can drag the scroll bar all the way to the bottom and it works fine but if you use a mouse wheel to scroll, it stops about 2/3 - 3/4 of the way down.

Here is the page: http://zimxtrial.ukbigbuy.com/#specification

Comment: Scrolls to the bottom for me.

Comment: @JamieHutber - You did use the scrollwheel didn't you and not the scrollbar?
Which browser are you using, I'm in chrome with that problem and in IE I am getting no scroll at all, I am guessing that could be due to the smoothWheel I have implemented, I will have to look and see what the support for that feature is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that the mouse wheel scrolling problem is associated with this peice of code in particular. The issue is with one of the libraries that you are using.

May I suggest you use the chrome dev tools and javascript console to debug the code (either using breakpoints or console.log), but in any case, the code above looks like it should be just picking the max height from the 3 divs, as long as your html markup is correct and there are no further divs that have the same class/id.

By the way, I would suggest you avoid using Javascript to resize divs, it is a problem best left to CSS. This code will get hairy really quickly, specially with the miriad of devices/screen sizes on the market. So hardcoding things like "maxHeight+24" and so on, is a trap that will double your efforts later on.

---

Edit:

Remove the code that sets a height for the outer div. Your page works fine without a height set on the div, it takes the height of the tallest div anyway.

Upon closer inspection, it appears that your scroll wheel issue is coming from the bit of javascript at the head of your document. Namely where you initialise your smoothscroll script and you do this:

`$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);`

This calls the onScroll method when your scrolling, so I assume that your problem can be narrowed down to what happens within that function. Debug.

p.s. do some cross browser testing too, your page looks vastly different in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox from what I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will have a look at your suggestions.

The reason I think it is that code is because it is the only thing that has changed since getting the error. The "maxHeight+24" is actually just to allow for the 24px padding that should be there but when I think about it, it would make a lot more sense just to add that to the css - it's Friday, my brain is finding complicated solutions to simple problems.

Is there a way to use CSS to get the same effect that I am getting at the moment, if you look at the page I linked in my OP you will see what I am aiming for.

Comment: My understanding is that you want 3 columns (represented by divs) to become the same height as the tallest div of the group?

Comment: Also, you said "no further divs that have the same class/id" - The class wouldn't matter would it? `.specification-columns` is used for all three columns, the ID's are only used once but I have many classes being used on different thing, one class for example is used on 15 div's.

Comment: I have 3 columns, each column will be a different size which is no problem, but I need to set their parent div to the same height as the tallest child. The problem with that is that the child divs are absolute but the parent is relative and I know a parent div will only take on the height of its children if they are also relative.

Comment: It would matter if `.specification-columns` is used elsewhere. Your call to `$('.specification-columns').each()` will take the maximum height of any div on the page with that class, not just the 3 columns you want. So if say you have another column up above somewhere with that class assigned that is really tall, it would screw up your calculations for these 3 columns.

Comment: Do you mean take out all of the code I pasted above? I tried that and the container divs height sets to 0.
I also see the problem with firefox, I will have to look into that, I don't know why things are moving out of place, it must be the css isn't supported in FF, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: The `smoothScroll` was the issue, I will have to look for a replacement that works cross-browser.

Comment: Glad to be of asssistance.